# Batch findstr condition

Tags: batch-file, conditional-statements, findstr

I've searched through quite a few answers, and can't seem to find what I'm looking for, so pardon me if it has been answered already. I've also never posted here, so excuse me if my formatting is wrong.

I'm trying to determine the OS of a server, either 2003 or 2008, and run a command based on the result. The .bat always goes straight to ":last". Here's what I have -

```
@echo off
cd\
set output="c:\osout.txt"
del %output%
set /p osinfo=Server? 

wmic /node:%osinfo% os get caption > "c:\osout.txt"


findstr "2003" "c:\osout.txt"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO ver2003
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO next
:next
findstr "2008" "c:\osout.txt"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO ver2008
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 GOTO last
:ver2003
cd\
cls
echo ver2003 
pause

:ver2008
cd\
cls
echo ver2008
pause

:last
cd\
cls
echo not 2003 or 2008
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
type "c:\osout.txt" | findstr /c:"2003"
```

Comment: As I found out, findstr doesn't support unicode, and WMIC outputs to unicode, so this approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`wmic` creates the output file in Unicode format, which isn't supported by `findstr`. Use `find` instead.

You can check the encoding of a text file by opening the file in Notepad and clicking *File → Save As…*. The field *Encoding* (bottom center of the *Save As* dialog) shows the actual encoding of the file.

Comment: Gah. Bad news. Do you know any other way to return OS information as fast as WMIC does? "systeminfo" takes forever to run, as it queries a lot more information than I need.

Comment: Like I said, you can use `find` (which supports Unicode) instead of `findstr`. Or `type` the file into `findstr` as Endoro suggested. `type` can read Unicode files and will print the output in ASCII.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you need: http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html
Put special atention to "Options" parameter.

options may be any combination of the following switches:

/I   Case-insensitive search.

/S   Search subfolders.

/P   Skip any file that contains non-printable characters.

/OFF[LINE] Do not skip files with the OffLine attribute set.

/L   Use search string(s) literally.

/B   Match pattern if at the Beginning of a line.

/E   Match pattern if at the END of a line.

/X   Print lines that match exactly.

/V   Print only lines that do NOT contain a match.

/N   Print the line number before each line that matches.

/M   Print only the filename if a file contains a match.

/O   Print character offset before each matching line.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think I've tried every possible combination of relevant options to no avail. I've also tried adding wildcard characters. Do you have any specific combination of options in mind that I should try?